# Surrogate model for [parameter vector] to [time series]

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

Say I have a function **F** that takes in a parameter vector **P** (say, a 5-element vector), and produces a (numerical) time series **Y[t]** of length *T* (eg *T*=100, so *t*=1,...,100). The function could be complicated (eg enzyme reaction models)

**I want to make a neural network that predicts the output (Y[t]) that would result from feeding a new parameter set (P') into the function. How can this be done?**

A simple feed-forward network can work, but it requires a very large number of output nodes, and doesn't take into account the temporal correlation / relationships between points. Is it possible/better to use a RNN or Transformer instead?

Comment: this doesn't suit the guidelines of a stackoverflow question, perhaps [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit. In the meantime, I would encourage you to look up one-to-many architectures of RNNs (or just the decoder stage of a seq2seq model.

Comment: You can use bidirectional LSTM for this problem, or you can use Reinforcement learning with RNN or you can use simple Transformer Decoder part for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RNN might work for you. Here is some example code in Keras to get you started:

```
param_length = 5
time_length = 100

hidden_size = 20

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Encode input parameters.
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_size, input_shape=[param_length]),

    # Generate a sequence.
    tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(time_length),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
])

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="nadam")
model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(val_x, val_y), epochs=10)
```

The first Dense layer converts input parameters to a hidden state. Then LSTM RNN units generate time sequences. You will need to experiment with hyperparameters like the number of dense and LTSM layers, the size of hidden layers etc.

One more thing you can try is to use different loss function like:

```
  early_stopping_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
      monitor="val_mae", patience=50, restore_best_weights=True)
  model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(), optimizer="nadam", metrics=["mae"])
  history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(val_x, val_y), epochs=500,
                      callbacks=[early_stopping_cb])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I notice that in your edit you changed the LSTM units to 32 (from 128) - is there any reason for this?

Comment: You are welcome! No particular reason, this is one of hyperparameters you would need to tune based on your data. Probably you can start using smaller number first and increase it if needed. or just try out different values and see what fits best to your data.

Comment: Besides hidden layer size you can also try out using different loss function, like mae. I have added the example to my answer above.